Can Slack OAuth 2.0 Authorization Work in a Private Network Without a Public Redirect URL Using Socket Mode
I'm currently working with Slack OAuth 2.0 authorization in a public environment using the standard OAuth flow. In this flow, we pass the Slack app's code to Slack, which uses a callback URL which is a publicly exposed redirect URL to obtain access and refresh tokens. This works perfectly for environments where the redirect URL can be public.
However, I am now dealing with a private network where the redirect URL cannot be publicly exposed. At the same time, I would like to take advantage of Slack's Socket Mode for real-time event communication via WebSockets, which does not require a public endpoint for event subscriptions.
My Questions:
Can I still use Socket Mode in a private network while performing the initial one-time OAuth 2.0 authorization flow?
Is there any workaround for handling the OAuth redirect URL in such private environments where exposing an HTTP endpoint isn't feasible?
